# Phone Damage (Micromax Knight 350) few days ago, anyway to recover photos?

Tags: photos

My phone got damaged a few days ago. I believe the phone is connected with Google Drive and Gmail account, but I have not installed Google Photos and Dropbox to my phone. Is there any way to get my photos back? Some important documents were there.

Answer (score 0):

There are ways, but you would need to elaborate a bit on the damaged part. Can you see the screen? Is it water damaged? What damage has it received. If you did not have a password on it. You may be able to connect it to a pc via USB cable and navigate through the folders to find the files you need.

Comment: My phone motherboard is damaged so I am not able to connect it to pc. Do you know any other idea to recover images only like from google server or any other way.

Comment: If you cannot get it to connect to a PC, then yes. The only way would be through google. You can check google pics or sometimes your google+ will have them.

Answer (score 0):

Your phone should of come with a Sd Card, if not,use the USB cable that came with the phone and hook it to a computer. The Sd Card comes out and you can put it in some computers

Comment: My phone doesn't have SD card its come with only internal memory.